# How to solve syntax error in product detail page in magento?

Tags: magento

I have an error only in product detail page in magento

```
SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ')' at line 1
```

if i set original default theme it is not giving me any error,
so what could be the issue?

```
There has been an error processing your request

SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ')' at line 1

Trace:
    #0 C:\wamp\www\dennymagic.com\store\lib\Varien\Db\Statement\Pdo\Mysql.php(110): Zend_Db_Statement_Pdo->_execute(Array)
    #1 C:\wamp\www\dennymagic.com\store\lib\Zend\Db\Statement.php(300): Varien_Db_Statement_Pdo_Mysql->_execute(Array)
   #2 C:\wamp\www\dennymagic.com\store\lib\Zend\Db\Adapter\Abstract.php(479): Zend_Db_Statement->execute(Array)
     #3 C:\wamp\www\dennymagic.com\store\lib\Zend\Db\Adapter\Pdo\Abstract.php(238): Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract->query('SELECT `mage_ca...', Array)
    #4 C:\wamp\www\dennymagic.com\store\lib\Varien\Db\Adapter\Pdo\Mysql.php(419): Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Abstract->query('SELECT `mage_ca...', Array)
     #5 C:\wamp\www\dennymagic.com\store\lib\Zend\Db\Adapter\Abstract.php(753): Varien_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql->query(Object(Varien_Db_Select), Array)
       #6 C:\wamp\www\dennymagic.com\store\app\code\core\Mage\Eav\Model\Entity\Abstract.php(943): Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract->fetchRow(Object(Varien_Db_Select))
     #7 C:\wamp\www\dennymagic.com\store\app\code\core\Mage\Catalog\Model\Resource\Abstract.php(698): Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Abstract->load(Object(Mage_Catalog_Model_Category), Object(Mage_Catalog_Model_Category), NULL)
     #8 C:\wamp\www\dennymagic.com\store\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Model\Abstract.php(225): Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Abstract->load(Object(Mage_Catalog_Model_Category), Object(Mage_Catalog_Model_Category), NULL)
       #9 C:\wamp\www\dennymagic.com\store\app\code\core\Mage\Catalog\Block\Product\List.php(80): Mage_Core_Model_Abstract->load(Object(Mage_Catalog_Model_Category))
       #10 C:\wamp\www\dennymagic.com\store\app\code\core\Mage\Catalog\Block\Product\List.php(141): Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_List->_getProductCollection()
      #11 C:\wamp\www\dennymagic.com\store\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Block\Abstract.php(862): Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_List->_beforeToHtml()
      #12 C:\wamp\www\dennymagic.com\store\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Block\Text\List.php(43): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->toHtml()
      #13 C:\wamp\www\dennymagic.com\store\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Block\Abstract.php(863): Mage_Core_Block_Text_List->_toHtml()
      #14 C:\wamp\www\dennymagic.com\store\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Block\Abstract.php(582): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->toHtml()
        #15 C:\wamp\www\dennymagic.com\store\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Block\Abstract.php(526): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->_getChildHtml('content', true)
      #16 C:\wamp\www\dennymagic.com\store\app\design\frontend\aaaa\bbb\template\page\2columns-right.phtml(36): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->getChildHtml('content')
         #17 C:\wamp\www\dennymagic.com\store\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Block\Template.php(241): include('C:\wamp\www\den...')
        #18 C:\wamp\www\dennymagic.com\store\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Block\Template.php(272): Mage_Core_Block_Template->fetchView('frontend\aaa...')
       #19 C:\wamp\www\dennymagic.com\store\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Block\Template.php(286): Mage_Core_Block_Template->renderView()
       #20 C:\wamp\www\dennymagic.com\store\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Block\Abstract.php(863): Mage_Core_Block_Template->_toHtml()
     #21 C:\wamp\www\dennymagic.com\store\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Model\Layout.php(555): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->toHtml()
       #22 C:\wamp\www\dennymagic.com\store\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Controller\Varien\Action.php(390): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->getOutput()
       #23 C:\wamp\www\dennymagic.com\store\app\code\core\Mage\Cms\Helper\Page.php(137): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->renderLayout()
     #24 C:\wamp\www\dennymagic.com\store\app\code\core\Mage\Cms\Helper\Page.php(52): Mage_Cms_Helper_Page->_renderPage(Object(Mage_Cms_IndexController), 'no-route')
     #25 C:\wamp\www\dennymagic.com\store\app\code\core\Mage\Cms\controllers\IndexController.php(75): Mage_Cms_Helper_Page->renderPage(Object(Mage_Cms_IndexController), 'no-route')
        #26 C:\wamp\www\dennymagic.com\store\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Controller\Varien\Action.php(419):  Mage_Cms_IndexController->noRouteAction()
     #27 C:\wamp\www\dennymagic.com\store\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Controller\Varien\Router\Standard.php(250): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->dispatch('noRoute')
   #28 C:\wamp\www\dennymagic.com\store\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Controller\Varien\Front.php(176): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard->match(Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http))
   #29 C:\wamp\www\dennymagic.com\store\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Model\App.php(354): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch()
      #30 C:\wamp\www\dennymagic.com\store\app\Mage.php(683): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
     #31 C:\wamp\www\dennymagic.com\store\index.php(87): Mage::run('', 'store')
```

Comment: What theme *does* give the error?

Comment: i have added code for error plz help

Answer (score 3):

Probably the error is related to some phtml files.

The theme files for prod detail are here:
**app/design/frontend/YOR_PACKAGE/YOUR_THEME/template/catalog/product/view/**

**RAW Solution:**

To find out the error I can suggest you to proceed in this way:
try to remove directory and then sub_directory in the template dir: **app/design/frontend/YOR_PACKAGE/YOUR_THEME/template/**

For example you can try remove this dir: **app/design/frontend/YOR_PACKAGE/YOUR_THEME/template/catalog/product/view/**
and see if the error is gone so you are sure that what is causing the error is a file inside this dir.

Once you find out the dir, repeat the operation removing file by file until you don't understand which file is.

At this point you can analize the file code.

**BETTER Solution**:

use Xdebug and follow the flow of the code until the error is triggered.