# getting error in product info page shows error as There has been an error processing your request

Tags: magento

When i was click on the product it redirecting to productinfo page after that it shoes error

```
a:5:{i:0;s:203:"SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ')' at line 1";i:1;s:4430:"#0 E:\wamp\www\magento\lib\Varien\Db\Statement\Pdo\Mysql.php(110): Zend_Db_Statement_Pdo->_execute(Array)
    #1 E:\wamp\www\magento\app\code\core\Zend\Db\Statement.php(291): Varien_Db_Statement_Pdo_Mysql->_execute(Array)
    #2 E:\wamp\www\magento\lib\Zend\Db\Adapter\Abstract.php(479): Zend_Db_Statement->execute(Array)
    #3 E:\wamp\www\magento\lib\Zend\Db\Adapter\Pdo\Abstract.php(238): Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract->query('SELECT `catalog...', Array)
    #4 E:\wamp\www\magento\lib\Varien\Db\Adapter\Pdo\Mysql.php(428): Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Abstract->query('SELECT `catalog...', Array)
    #5 E:\wamp\www\magento\lib\Zend\Db\Adapter\Abstract.php(753): Varien_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql->query(Object(Varien_Db_Select), Array)
    #6 E:\wamp\www\magento\app\code\core\Mage\Eav\Model\Entity\Abstract.php(943): Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract->fetchRow(Object(Varien_Db_Select))
    #7 E:\wamp\www\magento\app\code\core\Mage\Catalog\Model\Resource\Abstract.php(698): Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Abstract->load(Object(Mage_Catalog_Model_Category), Object(Mage_Catalog_Model_Category), NULL)
    #8 E:\wamp\www\magento\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Model\Abstract.php(225): Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Abstract->load(Object(Mage_Catalog_Model_Category), Object(Mage_Catalog_Model_Category), NULL)
    #9 E:\wamp\www\magento\app\code\core\Mage\Catalog\Block\Product\List.php(80): Mage_Core_Model_Abstract->load(Object(Mage_Catalog_Model_Category))
    #10 E:\wamp\www\magento\app\code\core\Mage\Catalog\Block\Product\List.php(142): Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_List->_getProductCollection()
    #11 E:\wamp\www\magento\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Block\Abstract.php(918): Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_List->_beforeToHtml()
    #12 E:\wamp\www\magento\app\design\frontend\base\default\template\page\html\header.phtml(149): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->toHtml()
    #13 E:\wamp\www\magento\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Block\Template.php(241): include('E:\wamp\www\mag...')
    #14 E:\wamp\www\magento\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Block\Template.php(272): Mage_Core_Block_Template->fetchView('frontend\base\d...')
    #15 E:\wamp\www\magento\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Block\Template.php(286): Mage_Core_Block_Template->renderView()
    #16 E:\wamp\www\magento\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Block\Abstract.php(919): Mage_Core_Block_Template->_toHtml()
    #17 E:\wamp\www\magento\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Block\Abstract.php(637): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->toHtml()
    #18 E:\wamp\www\magento\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Block\Abstract.php(581): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->_getChildHtml('header', true)
    #19 E:\wamp\www\magento\app\design\frontend\base\default\template\page\2columns-right.phtml(42): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->getChildHtml('header')
    #20 E:\wamp\www\magento\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Block\Template.php(241): include('E:\wamp\www\mag...')
    #21 E:\wamp\www\magento\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Block\Template.php(272): Mage_Core_Block_Template->fetchView('frontend\base\d...')
    #22 E:\wamp\www\magento\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Block\Template.php(286): Mage_Core_Block_Template->renderView()
    #23 E:\wamp\www\magento\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Block\Abstract.php(919): Mage_Core_Block_Template->_toHtml()
    #24 E:\wamp\www\magento\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Model\Layout.php(555): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->toHtml()
    #25 E:\wamp\www\magento\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Controller\Varien\Action.php(390): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->getOutput()
    #26 E:\wamp\www\magento\app\code\core\Mage\Cms\Helper\Page.php(137): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->renderLayout()
    #27 E:\wamp\www\magento\app\code\core\Mage\Cms\Helper\Page.php(52): Mage_Cms_Helper_Page->_renderPage(Object(Mage_Cms_IndexController), 'no-route')
    #28 E:\wamp\www\magento\app\code\core\Mage\Cms\controllers\IndexController.php(75): Mage_Cms_Helper_Page->renderPage(Object(Mage_Cms_IndexController), 'no-route')
    #29 E:\wamp\www\magento\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Controller\Varien\Action.php(418): Mage_Cms_IndexController->noRouteAction()
    #30 E:\wamp\www\magento\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Controller\Varien\Router\Standard.php(250): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->dispatch('noRoute')
    #31 E:\wamp\www\magento\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Controller\Varien\Front.php(172): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard->match(Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http))
    #32 E:\wamp\www\magento\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Model\App.php(354): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch()
    #33 E:\wamp\www\magento\app\Mage.php(684): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
    #34 E:\wamp\www\magento\index.php(87): Mage::run('', 'store')
    #35 {main}";s:3:"url";s:31:"/magento/index.php/samsung.html";s:11:"script_name";s:18:"/magento/index.php";s:4:"skin";s:7:"default";}
```

here where to check ?? i can't able to find where is the error field are getting error...
how to fix those issues ..
**which file i need to check??**

Comment: Your Product Info page has SQL errors

Comment: how to find that??means page or any keythings @Slimshadddyyy

Comment: can you show me the code of your app/design/frontend/YOR_PACKAGE/YOUR_THEME/template/catalog/product/view.php

Answer (score 0):

Probably the error is related to some phtml files.

The theme files for prod detail are here:

```
app/design/frontend/YOR_PACKAGE/YOUR_THEME/template/catalog/product/view/
```

RAW Solution:

To find out the error I can suggest you to proceed in this way:
try to remove directory and then sub_directory in the template dir:

```
app/design/frontend/YOR_PACKAGE/YOUR_THEME/template/
```

For example you can try remove this dir:

```
app/design/frontend/YOR_PACKAGE/YOUR_THEME/template/catalog/product/view/
```

and see if the error is gone so you are sure that what is causing the error is a file inside this dir.

Once you find out the dir, repeat the operation removing file by file until you don't understand which file is.

At this point you can analize the file code.

BETTER Solution:

use Xdebug and follow the flow of the code until the error is triggered.

Check this link

[syntex error in product detail page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11828298/how-to-solve-syntex-error-in-product-detail-page-in-magento)

Answer (score 0):

Go to the root of your installation and open up index.php
find the following line.

```
if (isset($_SERVER['MAGE_IS_DEVELOPER_MODE'])) {
    Mage::setIsDeveloperMode(true);
}
```

Change it to

```
   if (isset($_SERVER['MAGE_IS_DEVELOPER_MODE'])) {
        Mage::setIsDeveloperMode(true);
    }
    Mage::setIsDeveloperMode(true);
```

Then, refresh the page again, you will get more readable error to debug.